# Lambda where fails but string where works

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

Using the old MongoDB driver, I was able to perform the following query:

```
Query.Where("this.plan.sstats.used < this.plan.sstats.available")
```

But with the new one, I'm forced to write this:

```
builder.Filter
      .Where(t => t.Plan.StorageStats.UploadUsed < t.Plan.StorageStats.UploadAvailable)
```

These look the same, but the new one does not work and I receive this error message:

> Additional information: Unsupported filter: ({plan.sstats.used} <
>   {plan.sstats.available}).

The back-end version is currently the same, so I don't see any reason why this shouldn't continue to be able to work.

How do I fix this? Is there a better way of doing this, whilst maintaining atomicity?

Comment: When you say old/new what exact version are you using?

Comment: @Liam New is 2.4, previous was 1.something. I'm not at work anymore so I can't check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems MongoDb drive doesn't support it any more. Me personally see two possible solutions:

1) You  query bson, not your objects, that should work (i have tried with my sample data out):

```
FilterDefinition<BsonDocument> filter = 
    new BsonDocument("$where", "this.plan.sstats.used<this.plan.sstats.available");
```

Waht is bad on this approach: your should query your collection as `BsonDocument` collection.

2) You query your collection as `ToEnumerable()` and than just add your filter as `Where` linq statement. That will work too, but you loose querying data directly on `mongodb`.

3) You could use aggregation framework, i did it this way:

```
var result = collection.Aggregate()
        .Group(r => r.Plan.StorageStats.UploadUsed - r.Plan.StorageStats.UploadAvailable,
              r => new {r.Key, Plans= r.Select(t=>t.Plan)} )
        .Match(r=>r.Key < 0)
        .ToEnumerable()
        .SelectMany(r=>r.Plans);
```

Negative on aggregate is that you couldn't combine it with your other Filters you use in `Find()` call.

Comment: Maksim, thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, we've been using it to do an atomic update, whilst ensuring that certain conditions are met, so this approach won't work.

Comment: @john you still could work directly with bson (solution 1) , otherwise you will have to split your query and first read all id's that you need to update and than build contains filter.

Comment: That's what I was hoping to avoid :) Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

So, I'd also asked over on Mongo's JIRA and was given this as a potential alternative. I'm posting it here in case anyone is dissatisfied with Maksim's answer.

---

It's possible to create just a filter definition:

```
FilterDefinition<C> filter = new JsonFilterDefinition<C>("{ $where : \"this.plan.sstats.used < this.plan.sstats.available\" }");
```

Since strings can be converted to FilterDefinitions you could also write either of the following which both end up creating a `JsonFilterDefinition: var filter = (FilterDefinition<C>)"{ $where : \"this.plan.sstats.used < this.plan.sstats.available\" }";`

```
// or using an implicit conversion

FilterDefinition<C> filter = "{ $where : \"this.plan.sstats.used < this.plan.sstats.available\" }";
```

Comment: cool, it works? you doing plain json filter and getting your Plans objects back?